# Has anyone combined measurements of the Bell inequality with special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, bells-inequality

The Bell inequality as measured with polarization involved slits polarized in either the same or a different orientation with respect to the photon emitter.

If I understand and/or recall correctly, relativity posits that things in a reference frame that is moving with respect to the observers frame can be tilted because of foreshortening.

Has anybody tried measuring Bell's inequality when one of the measuring devices is moving at a high enough speed with respect to the other that it would be tilted enough to make a noticeable difference in the statistics?

I'm curious partly because it seems like there might be a violation of rotation symmetry for a given measurement in one reference frame, but not in another, thus calling into question certain symmetries and by Noether's theorem, certain conservation laws.

And, of course, since I think actual symmetry violation is highly unlikely, it might provide clues to a new framework for reconciling quantum mechanics and relativity because any such explanation would have to explain the observation of this experiment, and also preserve rotational symmetry.

Comment: Too I think that if nonlocality were true, then it implies one should consider both points for the measurement. Does this indicate that a minimum principle involving sum of measurement times by the two observers in relativity should be considered ?